# How to iterate an array containing more than one child array in typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular7

Sorry guys I have gone through similar question in stackoverflow and implemented some but didn't got my exact output.
I'm new to angular 7 as well as to typescript.
I have an array that may contain more than one array. This array coming during runtime so I don't know how much child array will be there in a single parent array.


For Example say I have an array:
`uniqueValues[]= [[MODERN TRADE,3959], [TRADITIONAL TRADE,2303], [ALL OTHER,1183]]`


**I want the output like:**
MODERN TRADE
 
3959
TRADITIONAL TRADE
2303
ALL OTHER
1183

What I Did:

```
getUniqueValues(name){
    this.temps.columns.forEach(element => {
      if(element.name.toUpperCase() === name.toUpperCase()){

        // it is successfully populating as you can see i have displayed it in console
        this.uniqueValues= element.stats.frequencyDistribution;

        // so the above array looks like the array defined in the starting of this post
        console.log(this.uniqueValues);
      }
      });

      for(let i = 0; i < this.uniqueValues.length; i++){
        let childArray = this.uniqueValues[i];

        for(let j = 0; j < childArray.length; j++){
          console.log(childArray[j]);
        }
      }
  }
```

But it displays output like:
[,
M
O
D
E
R
N

T
R
A
D
E
,
3
9
5
9

can anybody show me the path?

Comment: `uniqueValues[]= [[MODERN TRADE,3959], [TRADITIONAL TRADE,2303], [ALL OTHER,1183]]` is invalid syntax, unfortunately...

Comment: This output suggests that `childArray` is actuallly a *string*. You probably have `["[MODERN TRADE,3959]", "[TRADITIONAL TRADE,2303]", "[ALL OTHER,1183]"]`

Comment: @mplungjan i have written it for display purpose the array we are getting is in runtime so the values are successfully populating the iuniqueValues[]

Comment: @mplungjan TS doesn't change array syntax - a JS array literal is a TS array literal and vice versa.

Comment: @mplungjan sure, the code wouldn't run if that was the code but the point is *we don't know what the actual code is*. We can't debug invalid representation of an application.

Comment: @CertainPerformance this one i have taken from console so it's looking like this in my .ts file everything is there it is for demostration purpose i have shown it like this just consider it is a array

Comment: I have changed the code plz have a look

Comment: No need for all the waffle. the code you posted seems to run when I do `const uniqueValues = [
  ["MODERN TRADE", "3959"],
  ["TRADITIONAL TRADE", "2303"],
  ["ALL OTHER", "1183"]
]; 
for (let i = 0; i < uniqueValues.length; i++) {
  let childArray = uniqueValues[i];

  for (let j = 0; j < childArray.length; j++) {
    console.log(childArray[j]);
  }
}`

Comment: `//it is successfully populating as you can see i have displayed it in console` but `this.uniqueValues= element.stats.frequencyDistribution;` *overwrites* `this.uniqueValues` every iteration. Please show that `this.uniqueValues` actually contains.

Answer (score 0):

For an ES6 and more readable, functional solution:

```
const myData = [['MODERN TRADE',3959], ['TRADITIONAL TRADE',2303], ['ALL OTHER',1183]];

const processedData = myData.reduce((output, curr) => {
  const [name, value] = curr;
  output += `${name}\n${value}\n`;
  return output;
}, '');
```

And because tsc 3.6.3 doesn't actually infer the tuple type, it is an ambiguous type to be fair, to be `[string, number]` but instead assigns the array type union `(string | number)[]` you can explicitly type your data identifier to be:

```
const myData: Array<[string, number]> = [['MODERN TRADE',3959], ['TRADITIONAL TRADE',2303], ['ALL OTHER',1183]];
```

Notice that each child element is a [Tuple](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#tuple) type in TypeScript.

Answer (score -1):

Use `forEach` -

```
uniqueValues.forEach(function (child) {
  child.forEach(function (childChild) {  
    console.log(childChild);
  });  
});
```